# Multiple logics (N number of clients) handled with only one function. All call the same function, HOW TO?

Tags: function

I have a corporate application written in python/Django (no python experience required to answer this). Its SAAS  basically.
Few of the clients seems to have different requirement for a few modules.
Lets say there is a URL 
www.xyz.com/groups 
which is used by all clients but a few of the clients want to have different output on call of the same URL.
I want to know how can i do that without writing new function for each client or writing conditions in a single function.
Its a silly question i know but there must be some solution to it, i know.

Comment: Strategy pattern with strategy selected dynamically depending on ClientID?

Comment: thx for the great solution. This pattern involves a lot of abstraction and when i implement that abstraction i'll write a derived function for each client. Is there any way that i can write a single function with constants that are handled from a calling function or a global constants file? Thx once again

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the "constants handled from a calling function" part of the question.

Comment: Lets say i have a function get_all_groups(). This function is used by User A to fetch all groups and list them, and a User B to fetch all groups and the related group details as well. Now there are two different requirements for both users. Normally one would make some if elses on the basis of User type or use a separate function for separate User types. I want something auto so that my code is not full of conditions. Is there any good way to do that. In abstraction you still have to override function and rewrite it again for each User type. What would you say to this?

Comment: I'll respond as a full post in a few minutes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is required to do "A" for case "a" and "B" for case "b" and "C" for case "c", then regardless of what solution you pick, somewhere in the code has to exists something that decides whever or not case 'a/b/c' occurs, and something must exist that will dispatch correct 'A/B/C' action for that case, and of course those A/B/C actions have to be written somewhere in the code, too.

Step outside of the code and think about it. If it is specified and must happen - it has to be coded somewhere. You cannot escape that. Now, if the cases/actions are trivial and typical, you might find some more-or-even-more configurable library that accidentally allows you to configure such cases and actions, and off you go, you have it "with no code" and no "clutter". But looking formally, the code is deep there in the library. So, the decider, dispatcher and actions are coded. Just not by you - by someone that guessed your needs.

But if your needs are nontrivial and highly specific, for example, if it require your various conditions to decide which a/b/c case is it - then most probably you will have to code the 'decider' part for yourself. That means lots of tree-of-IFs, nested-switches, rules-n-loops, or whatever you like or feel adequate. After this, you are left with dispatch/execute phase, and this can be realized in a multitude of ways - i.e. strategy pattern - it is exactly it: dispatch (by concrete class related to case) and execute (the concrete strategy has the concrete code for the case).

Let's try something-like-OO approach:

For example, if you have cases a/b/c for UserTypes U1,U2,U3, you could introduce three classes:

```
UserType1 inherits from abstract UserType or implements "DoAThing" interface
UserType2 inherits from abstract UserType or implements "DoAThing" interface
UserType3 inherits from abstract UserType or implements "DoAThing" interface

UserType1 implements virtual method 'doTheThing' that executes actionA
UserType2 implements virtual method 'doTheThing' that executes actionB
UserType3 implements virtual method 'doTheThing' that executes actionC

your Users stop keeping "UserType" of type "int" equal to '1/2/3' - now their type is an object: UserType1, UserType2 or UserType3
```

whenever you must do the thing for a given user, you now just:

```
result = user.getType().doTheThing( ..params..)
```

So, instead of iffing/switching, you use OO: `tell, don't ask` rule. If the action-to-do is dependent solely on UserType, then let the UserType perform it. The resulting code is as short as possible - but at the cost of number of classes to create and, well, ...

... the decider, dispatcher and actions are still in the code. Actions - obvious - in the various usertype clasess. Dispatch - obvious - virtual call by common abstract base method. And decider..? Well: someone at some point **had to choose and construct the correct UserType object for the user**. If user was stored in the database, if "usertype" is just an integer 1/2/3, then somewhere in your ORM layer those 1/2/3 numbers had to be decoded and translated into UserType1/2/3 classes/objects. That means, that you'd need there a tree-of-ifs or a switch or etc. Or, if you have an ORM smart enough - you just set up a bunch of rules and it did it for you, but that's just again delegating part of the job to more-or-even-more configurable library. Not mentioning that your UserType1/2/3 classes in fact became somewhat .. strategies.

Ok, let's attack the 'choose' part.

You can build a tree of ifs or switches somewhere to decide and assign, but imperative seems to smell. Or, with OO, you can try to polymorphize something so that "it will just do the right thing", but it will not solve anything since again you will have to choose the object type somewhere. So, let's try data-driven: let's use lookups.

```
we've got five implementations of an action
create a hash/dictionary/map
add usertype1->caseA to the map
add usertype2->caseC to the map
add usertype3->caseB to the map
add usertype4->caseA to the map
add usertype5->caseE to the map
....
```

now, whenever you have a user and need to decide, just look it up. Instead of a "case" you may hold a ready to use object of a strategy. Or a callable method. Or a typename. Or whatever you need. The point is that instead of writing

```
if( user.type == 1) { ... }
else if( user.type == 2)  ...
```

or switching, you just look it up:

```
thing = map[ user.type ]
if ( thing is null ) ???
```

but, mind that without some care, you might sometimes NOT find a match in the map. And also, the map must be PREDEFINED for ALL CASES. So, simple `if X < 100` may turn up into a **hundred** of entries 0..99 inside the map.

Of course, instead of a map, you may use some rule-engine and you could define a mapping like

```
X<100 -> caseA
X>=100 -> caseB
```

and then 'run' the rules against your usertype and obtain a 'result' that will tell you "caseA".

And so on.

Each of the parts - decide, dispatch, execute - you may implement in various ways, shorter or longer, more or less extensible, more or less configurable, as OO/imperative/datadriven/functional/etc - but you cannot escape them:

- you have to define the discriminant of the cases
- you have to define the implementation of the actions
- you have to define the mapping case-to-action

How to do them, is a matter of your aesthetics, language features, frameworks, libraries and .. time you want to spend on creating and mantaining it.

Comment: I must say, im pretty impressed with your answer and, you have answered it in the best way. Multiple answers in one answer. Very nice and thanks a lot bud.